# javascript equality operators why return false after to toLowerCase() even the strings are same (utf-8)?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to run this code in javascript

```js
const upperCase = "İ"
const lowerCase = "i"
const newLowerCase=upperCase.toLowerCase();

console.log(lowerCase);
console.log(newLowerCase);
// expected output: true, return false
console.log(newLowerCase == lowerCase);
```

this is returning true

```js
console.log("i".includes("i"))
```

but this is also returning true

```js
console.log("İ".toLowerCase().includes("i"))
```

This must be about characters in Turkish Language but I couldn't figure it out why this happening.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Is it really a problem? When will you really compare a function lowercase result to a literal? When you can capture the actual result?

Comment: const upperCase = "YEŞİL" is probably wrong, change to uppercase I and it will work fine  i.e. const upperCase = "YEŞIL"

Comment: Upvoted cyrille good catch

Comment: `newLowerCase.length` gives it away: there's a `\u0307` character in it

Comment: @cyrille input cannot be wrong - it is what it is.

Comment: upper case of `i` is `I` and not that random character `İ`

Answer (score 2):

The output of `"İ".toLowerCase()` is a lower case `i` with an additional `\u0307` "combining dot above".

That is, the result is `\u0069\u0307`.

This string therefore *does* include the lower case `i`, hence the true result for `.include`, but it does not *equal* a lower case `i`.

Answer (score 2):

to solved this use toLocaleLowerCase() function.

```js
const upperCase = "İ"
const lowerCase = "i"
const newLowerCase=upperCase.toLocaleLowerCase('tr-TR');

console.log(lowerCase);
console.log(newLowerCase);
// expected output: true, return true
console.log(newLowerCase == lowerCase);
```

if somehow does not work you can also use this

```js
    const upperCase = "İ"
    const lowerCase = "i"
    const newLowerCase=upperCase.replace(/İ/g,"i").toLowerCase();

    console.log(lowerCase);
    console.log(newLowerCase);
    // expected output: true, return true
    console.log(newLowerCase == lowerCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of translation problem with regards to the I looking character.

```
false: console.log("YEŞİL".toLowerCase().includes("yeşil"))
true:  console.log("YEŞL".toLowerCase().includes("yeşl"))
```

Comment: I just realize that the problem is "İ" character. I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

you are using a character which is not the uppercase I, but a unicode character. If you try the following that will explain why the == operator returns false

"İ".charCodeAt(0) => 304
"I".charCodeAt(0) => 73

304 is different from 73

"İ".toLowerCase().length => 2
"I".toLowerCase().length => 1

results have not the same length

"İ".toLowerCase().charCodeAt() => 105 (which is lowercase i)
"İ".toLowerCase().charCodeAt(1) => 775

The additional character is the lowercase of the dot above you had - https://www.codetable.net/decimal/775